# Open Cart, Want to create multiple parent categories

Tags: php, opencart

Currently I have multiple categories in my open cart shop. like A1, A2, A3 ... and their respective subcategories.

Now I want to create two new parents like A and B, where parent A will have child like A1, A2, A3... and their respective subcategories. Similarly parent B will have child like B1, B2, B3 ... and their respective subcategories...

Any clue.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new category A and B, then go to category A1, A2, A3 and change their parent category from *nothing* to *Category A*. Do the same for the Bx categories. However this question does not belong to StackOverflow and should be asked at OpenCart forums instead...

Comment: It doesn't belong on SO but it seems redundant to remake categories like this. Probably some bad design thinking on the side of the database.